# What happened to `column-span: <integer>`

Tags: css, columnspan

searching for this functionality, i came across the 2001 draft, which specified `column-span` to be defined as `none | all | <integer> | inherit`. i don’t get the `none` (spans no columns? does that mean `display:none`‽), but other than that, it’s nice. it even comes with this useful picture.

[image: column-span: 2]

code is sth. along the lines of:

```
article { column-count: 3 }
h1 { column-span: all }
h2 { column-span: 2 }
```

a bit history: it was abolished in 2005. 2007, it was re-introduced with the values `1 | all`, wich became `none | all` 2011 (reintroducting the nonsensical `none`).

my question: why was this property so badly curtailed? is there any reasoning behind that? (and behind the `none`)

Comment: The last time I used column-span it was spelled colspan

Comment: then you didn’t use the css3 multi-column property `column-span` this question is about, but the html table cell property `colspan` ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [current draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/CR-css3-multicol-20110412/) at least, the property name `column-span` effectively means “spans several columns” and the value `none` means “no” or “false.” In the [December 2009 draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/CR-css3-multicol-20091217/#column-span), things were more natural, so that the property could be interpreted as “number of columns spanned” and the initial value was `1` and not `none`.

In general, identifiers in CSS are often misleading and may reflect various stages of planning—think about `white-space`, which affects line breaking in general, not just text, or `letter-spacing`, which affects all characters, not just letters.

Based on what I have read in various discussions, the reason for limiting the values to just two (no spanning, spanning all) is that implementing other values would be essentially different and more complicated. Moreover, the demand for such a feature appears to be considerably more limited than for the basic functionality.

This sounds realistic, especially since even the very basic multi-column layout has so poor support: I don’t think any major browser supports it under the proposed standard names (but some support it under their browser-specific property names), and there does not seem to be any support even to `column-span: all` under any name. (Rumors say Safari supports it, but my tests on the Win 7 version don’t confirm this.)

Comment: thanks, good answer! could you link to one or more of the mentioned discussions?

Comment: @flying sheep, Minutes and Resolutions 2011-09-21 http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2011Sep/0377.html  discuss (tangentially) the effect of column-span with number value as meaning “floats.”